# Android Voice Call to Desktop

Tags: java, android, c, windows, linux

I was doing an application for android users where i wan guidelines , how to start my application..? 


**My app : App takes voice talks from the user and shutdown or switch user my desktop or atleast open any file in desktop.(windows/Linux pc)**

Pl help me .

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please go through the instructions mentioned the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080401/is-there-a-speech-to-text-api-by-google)

then make close look to the android speech api guidelines  mentioned below the link

[google speech api tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-guide/Recognition.html)